# Function to return min and max of column conditional on value of another column

Tags: r

I'm still new to R and need some assistance writing a function. I want to call dataframe "x" and tell R to return the maximum (non-missing) value in column "z"  over all rows whose value in a third column, y, are equal to 1, and the minimum over all rows where y=0, respectively. (Here, "y" and "z" in {0,1} are constants for simplification.)

I imagine it will look something like this:

```
EVB <- function(x) {
  subset(x, x$y == 0)
  return max(na.omit(x$z))
  subset(x, x$y == 1)
  return min(na.omit(x$z))
}
```

However, I get the following error when trying to define it, so I'm certain this is not the proper way to write such a function - perhaps because I'm wrapping a function within another function (subset)?

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  subset(x, x$y == 0)
  return max"
```

Many thanks in advance!!

MWE (apologies for my sloppy code):

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(888)

Z <- as.integer(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=20))
Y <- as.integer(sample(c(-28:50), replace=TRUE, size=20))
R0 <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.7)
R1 <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.7)

df <- data.frame(col1=Z, col2=Y, col3=R0, col4=R1)

names(df) <- c("Z", "Y", "R0", "R1") # oops


Attrition <- df$Y
df <- cbind(df, Attrition)
df$Attrition[c(1,5,7,9,17)] <- NA 

df$R0 <- as.integer(df$R0)
df$R1 <- as.integer(df$R1)

df$upperb <- df$Attrition
df$lowerb <- df$Attrition
```

**UPDATE**

Problem solved. Part of my problem was that I had accidentally been defining NAs as characters. With that fixed, the following solutions should work.

based on akrun's code - not tested

```
  EVB <- function(x) { 
  x1 <- x[x[["Z"]]==0, 
          , drop=FALSE]; 
  Mx <- max(na.omit(x1[["Attrition"]])); 
  x2 <- x[x[["Z"]]==1,, 
          drop=FALSE]; 
  Mn <- min(na.omit(x1[["Attrition"]])); 
  list(Mn, Mx) 
  }

EVB(df)
```

based on Alpha Beta Gamma's code - works, confirmed

```
EVB <- function(x) { 
  ind <- x[["Z"]]==0 
  Mx <- max(x[["Attrition"]][ind], na.rm = TRUE); 
  ind <- x[["Z"]]==1
  Mn <- min(x[["Attrition"]][ind], na.rm = TRUE); 
  list(Mn, Mx)  ## or return(list(Mn, Mx))
  }

EVB(df)
```

Comment: Inside a function, it is better not to use `subset` and also `$`.  Instead use `[`.  Also, the `subset` output is not assigned to any object i.e. without that it is meaningless to do subset.  What you need might be `EVB <- function(x) { x1 <- x[x[["y"]]==0, , drop=FALSE]; Mx <- max(na.omit(x1[["z"]])); x2 <- x[x[["y"]]==1,, drop=FALSE]; Mn <- min(na.omit(x1[["z"]])); list(Mn, Mx) }`

Comment: I posted my comment as a solution.

Comment: Use `NA`, not `"NA"`, otherwise you make Attrition into a character/string column.

Comment: If you just want to get an overview of the data, you can do `lapply(split(df$Attrition, df$Z), summary)`

Comment: @Frank "NA" was definitely part of my problem, thanks. However, Mx and Mn still return elements not in their respective Z==z. The answer is probably silly.

Comment: @AlphaBetaGamma Nope, I still haven't found the right answer.

Comment: Solved. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is because `return` is a function. You should do `return(max(na.omit(x$z)))`.

Similarly, `subset` is also a function, and it has returned value. You need do `temp <- subset(x, x$y == 1)`, where you get a new data frame `temp`. Then you take maximum `max(na.omit(temp$z))`.

A function will terminate when seeing a `return`. If you want this function to return both values, take akrun's advice. Use a `list` to hold all multiple output. In R, this is the **only** way to ask a function for multiple output.

akrun mentioned that `return` is not need in R, well, in some situations it is true. For example, you don't have branches in your function, that require different return. But like:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    x <- rnorm(ceil(x), 0, 1)
    return(x);
    } else {
    x <- -x  ## it is good to leave space, otherwise "<--" is confusing
    return(sqrt(x))
    }
  }
```

You have to use return. Also, note how I used `if...else...`, `else` **must** be after the `}` in the same line, otherwise if does not work. Why? Because it is legal in R to take an `if` without `else`. If you separate them, R will assume the first `if` independent, then report error when meeting an `else`.

Back to `return`. Even if when there is no branching output, you still be careful in returning values.

```
foo <- function (x) x <- x + 1
```

will return nothing. You have to do:

```
foo <- function (x) return(x + 1)
```

or

```
foo <- function (x) {
  x <- x + 1
  x
  }
```

Then final `x` is ask R to print/output that value.

akrun also gives you advice to use `[[]]` for subsetting. That is true. Though I told you how to use `subset` correctly in above, you don`t want to use it, as it is costly: you copy the data frame!

Perhaps you need a good reference for learning/using R. [R CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/)
website has a "manual" link on the left side, and the "introduction to R" should be a first-hand reference for you. It is (always) up to date. Never use other guide, or you may get into trouble, like this one did: [Unable to Replicate "R for Beginners" Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394461/unable-to-replicate-r-for-beginners-example).

Have fun with R, and hopefully you like my explanation.

---

Back to your question. It is amazing that it takes three people to work around. Because we have all assumed your data are numeric. Only when I step into debugging mode had I see what's wrong.

Your `df` has strings for `Attrition`:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Z        : int  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ Y        : int  7 -3 48 27 22 2 27 14 -11 10 ...
 $ R0       : int  0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ R1       : int  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Attrition: chr  "NA" "-3" "48" "27" ...
 $ upperb   : chr  "NA" "-3" "48" "27" ...
 $ lowerb   : chr  "NA" "-3" "48" "27" ...
```

But `mix` and `max` takes numeric. You have to cast! Why this happen, because previously you did

```
df$Attrition[c(1,5,7,9,17)] <- "NA"
```

Originally `Attrition` is integer, but `"NA"` is a string version of `NA`. After your assignment you change `Attrition` from integer class to string class. You should simply do

```
df$Attrition[c(1,5,7,9,17)] <- NA
```

Then this will be correct:

```
EVB <- function(x) { 
  ind <- x[["Z"]]==0 
  Mx <- max(x[["Attrition"]][ind], na.rm = TRUE); 
  ind <- x[["Z"]]==1
  Mn <- min(x[["Attrition"]][ind], na.rm = TRUE); 
  list(Mn, Mx)  ## or return(list(Mn, Mx))
  }
```

I have specially used `na.rm` argument in `min`, `max`. I am not saying `na.omit` is bad, it is just that people often forget that many basic R summary function has `na.rm` as a handy option.

Comment: I think a correct example would look more like...`if (x > 0){ return(x) }; -x`. Then, without the return, the function performs incorrectly for some input. It's for early termination here.

Comment: @AlphaBetaGamma This is a very thorough response, thanks. I'm having trouble applying it though. Struggling to envision what it would look like in this case. Referring to the MWE, something like `EVB <- function(x)
  if subset(x, Z==0) 
  return(max(x$Attrition)) 
  if subset(x, Z==1) 
  return(min(x$Attrition))
  else return(-x)
}` ?

Comment: @AlphaBetaGamma your example correctly returns the max but not the min. This is true whether I define the min as ind2 or switch the order of Mx, Mn. What's going wrong?

Comment: Yes - although that wasn't the problem. The problem was me reading the output incorrectly! My apologies. I think this is something labeling would fix. Right now the output reads "[[1]]
[1] -18

[[2]]
[1] 43." This is a separate question, but is it possible to rename [[1]] and [[2]]?

Answer (score 3):

It is better not to use `$`, `subset` inside a function.  Instead, we can try with `[`, `[[`.  Another problem in the OP's function is the `subset` output is not assigned to any object

```
 EVB <- function(x) {
   x1 <- x[x[["y"]]==0, , drop=FALSE]
   Mx <- max(na.omit(x1[["z"]]))
   x2 <- x[x[["y"]]==1,, drop=FALSE]
   Mn <- min(na.omit(x2[["z"]]))
  list(Mn, Mx)
 }
```

If we are using `subset`

```
 x1 <- subset(x, y==0)
```

and

```
 x2 <- subset(x, y==1)
```

Note that I didn't use `$` inside a `subset`.  It is not needed. Also, in `R`, the `return` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks! Still, although there are no errors, this doesn't appear to return the correct results. I posted a MWE if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: My apologies, the incorrect results were due to the NAs being mistakenly defined as character strings in my MWE. Your code should work.